# PHP what is more efficent file_exists or elseif chain

Tags: php, performance

I have an app that pulls data from an API.

One of the fields I am displaying (lets call it $name) may or may not have an image associated with it in a directory on my server.

When I originally wrote the code I used an elseif block to set the  tag for known images, it looks something like this....

```
 if($name == "fred")
 {
    $image = "<img src='/images/fred.png'>";
 }
 elseif($name == "jon")
 {
    $image = "<img src='/images/jon.png'>";
 }
 ......
 else
 {
    $image = $name; // just the text
 }
```

We are up to 15 images in the elseif block, and there will be more in the future, so I'm wondering if switching to file_exists will be more efficient, something like:

```
$filename = '/path/to/images/'.$name;
if (file_exists($filename)) {
     echo "<img src='".$filename."'>";
} else {
    echo $name;
}
```

This image is set often so I'd like it to be as efficient as possible.

Look forward to any thoughts...

Comment: It's not as though the two options are doing the same thing, so you're not comparing like with like

Comment: Using your `if($name == "fred")` doesn't actually check if the image exists, so what happens if you've actually deleted it from disk? Broken image icons on a web page look amateurish

Comment: Hey Mark, they are both setting the image (or text if image does not exist). Its 2 different ways to do the same thing, my question is which if more efficient...

Comment: And as the series of if/elseif/else tests grows, it will become slower and slower (and harder to maintain as you add new tests) for those further down in the set of tests

Comment: no they're not both doing the same thing... using file_exists() will never leave you with a broken image icon, your if/elseif/else structure can, so there are differences

Comment: Your 2nd point is a good one Mark, so far its been maintainable because I only add the ones I know an image exists for, but could get confusing in the future...

Comment: Even `$names = array('fred','jon','dilbert'...); if (in_array($name, $names)) { $image = "<img src='/images/'.$name.'.png'>"; } else { echo $name; }` would be more efficient than a whole series of `if/elseif/else` as the list grows

Comment: thanks everyone, went with `if(file_exists($filename))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely better to use `file_exists()`. You are trying to do something that is called `premature optimization` and it's not good thing.

Maybe this check is more expensive than simple `if`, but you'll not notice this in your script. And of course `if`s will be harder to maintain (and that what you should think about while writing code).

Of course if you've got many images then `file_exists()` can be more efficient way to check if file is there than checking many `if`s.

Comment: This is also pretty much speculation. Efficiency that is asked about remains unspecified, hence I find it hard how an answer can be of use. No -1 so far because the warning about premature optimization isn't that bad and preventing the worst a bit.

Comment: @hakre OP didn't specify how many images is there. But generally with more images `file_exists()` will win in performance anyway.

Comment: Now you ruin the premature optimization warning ;)

Comment: @hakre Not really :) I just added next advantage for using `file_exists()`.

Comment: No, what I mean is that you can not say what of those two is better because it's not clear what this is actually about. I suspect that both alternatives are very wrong and that the problem lacks encapsulation. But that's perhaps only my opinion :)

Comment: @hakre Why both are very wrong? `file_exists()` wins because of easier maintaining which is more important than "some" performance improvement.

Comment: Because you do not have enough information at hand with the question. You still have a good nose to prefer the file-system here probably, but the answer might be as well totally wrong. So sometimes it is better to not provide guesses but just make a clean statement that it can not be said and that different situations need different solutions or similar. For example, question the if. Why is there one if needed anyway? Why branch at that place in the code?